# How to start a shell script in one minute later in linux?

Tags: bash

How to start a shell script in one minute later?

Suppose there are two bash files a.sh and b.sh
I want to execute b.sh one minute(or several seconds) after a.sh executed.
what should  I code in a.sh ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simple. you want to use 'at' to schedule your job. and 'date' to calculate your moment in the future.

Example:

```
echo b.sh | at now + 1 minute
```

or:

```
echo b.sh | at -t `date -v+60S "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
```

`-v+60S` adds 60 seconds to current time. You can control exactly how many seconds you want to add.

But usually, when people wants one program to launch a minute after the other, they are not 100% sure it will not take more or less than a minute. that's it. `b.sh` could be launched before `a.sh` is finished. or `a.sh` could have finished 30 seconds earlier than "planned" and b.sh could have started faster.

I would recommend a different model. Where `b.sh` is launched first.
`a.sh` creates a temp file when it starts. execute is tasks and delete its temp file at the end.
`b.sh` watch for the temp file to be created, then deleted. and start its tasks.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It exactly what I want. But there is a bit mistake perhaps? It says " Date invalid option --v"

Comment: @alexchan: Different versions of `date` support different options. Try: `echo b.sh | at now + 1 minute`

Comment: Will the b.sh be execute in a visual window ? and how?

Comment: It does not execute b.sh anyway, I don't know why

Comment: @alexchan right after added the at job but before the minute is spent. try running atq, it should show your job. also, you can look into your system logs and find out when the command was run. as for opening the command in a window. this is a whole different question. your at command would need to run the terminal of your choice. you will need to find out how to feed the command to your terminal. and your at ENV will need to have a DISPLAY var set properly.

Comment: On Ubuntu I am getting an error: date: invalid option -- 'v'

Answer (score 4):

Make the final line of a.sh:

```
sleep 60 && b.sh
```

(If b.sh is not in a directory in PATH, make that a full path to b.sh.)

Answer (score 3):

You can just `sleep`:

```
a.sh
sleep 60
b.sh
```

Or for more complicated cases you can use the `at` command:

```
echo b.sh | at now + 1 minute
```

See the `at` man page for more information.

Comment: No , it does execute b.sh as expected BTW, how to execute it after 10 seconds ? I changed the minute to second , it says syntax error.

Comment: @alexchan: `at` doesn't do time increments finer than one minute.

Comment: sleep 60 will actually hold the loggin process for 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `at` command.

See [`man at`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) for how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command to sleep your script for 1 minute.

```
sleep 1m
```

Then when you wish to call the 2nd script

```
bash a.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the second script some number of seconds after the *start* of the first script, you can do this in the first:

```
b.sh &
```

and this in the second:

```
sleep 10
# more commands
```

You could pass the number of seconds as an argument from the first to the second.

Unfortunately, `at` doesn't do time increments finer than one minute.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule both the scripts to run at the same time in cron and put the required delay in b.sh.